# Hide the external links

Tags: org-mode

I am insert a external link to `projects.org` from `os.org`

[image]

```
* file:projects.org::[[Workflow]]
```

How  could hide the external file name and left only workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[[link destination][link description]]` syntax:

```
[[file:projects.org::Workflow][Workflow]]
```